# How do I completely suppress paragraph indentation in quoting environment without \noindent?

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs, quoting

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.,align=left,leftmargin=*,
 labelsep=1.5em}

\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=1em}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 27}
Take the following q-valuation:
\begin{quoting}
  The domain is \{Romeo,Juliet,Benedick,Beatrice\}

  \noindent Constants are assigned references as follows:
  \begin{quoting}
    \texttt{`m'}$\Rightarrow$Romeo

    \noindent\texttt{`n'}$\Rightarrow$Juliet
  \end{quoting}

  \noindent Predicates are assigned extensions as follows:
  \begin{quoting}
    `F'$\Rightarrow$\{Romeo,Benedick\}\\
    `G'$\Rightarrow$\{Juliet,Beatrice\}\\
    `L'$\Rightarrow$\{<Romeo,Juliet>,<Juliet,Romeo>,<Benedick,
    Beatrice><Beatrice,Benedick>,<Benedick,Benedick>\}
  \end{quoting}
\end{quoting}
Then what are the truth values of the following wffs?
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item $\exists xLmx$
\item $\forall xLxm$
\item $(\exists xLmx\supset Lmn)$
\item $\forall x(Fx\equiv\neg Gx)$
\item $\forall x(Gx\supset(Lxm\vee\neg Lmx))$
\item $\forall x(Gx\supset\exists yLxy)$
\item $\exists x(Fx\wedge\forall y(Gy\supset Lxy))$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I want to suppress paragraph indentation in quoting environment concisely without `\noindent`.

Beside the issue, I have a line that doesn't break before the right side of the page. How do I fix it? I want to typeset as below. Ignore the yellow highlighting in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to suppress the environment indentation (not the paragraph indentation)?

Comment: @Bernard I want to suppress paragraph indentation `inside` quoting environment.

Comment: Use the `indentfirst=false` option.

Comment: @Bernard `indentfirst=false` resulted in unexpected paragraph indentations.

Comment: Why are you using quotation environments here exactly?

Comment: @cfr To indent some parts. I probably want to disable paragraph indentation globally.

Comment: So is that the output you want but not the code you want?

Comment: @cfr I added a second picture to the question. It describes what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend abusing quotation environments here. Not that abusing them is generally bad - they are just lists, basically - but I think something like an `array` or `tabular` is more suitable.

Here's an `assign` environment:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=3\parindent,labelwidth=\parindent, align=left}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=1em}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newenvironment{assign}[1]{%
  \noindent #1
  \medskip\par\noindent
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{>{\ttfamily\arraybackslash}l!{$\Rightarrow$}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  }{\endtabularx\medskip\par\noindent}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 27}
Take the following q-valuation:
\begin{quoting}
  The domain is \{Romeo,Juliet,Benedick,Beatrice\}

  \begin{assign}{Constants are assigned references as follows:}
    `m'&Romeo\\
    `n'&Juliet\\
  \end{assign}
  \begin{assign}{Predicates are assigned extensions as follows:}
    `F'&\{Romeo,Benedick\}\\
    `G'&\{Juliet,Beatrice\}\\
    `L'&\{<Romeo,Juliet>, <Juliet,Romeo>, <Benedick,Beatrice>, <Beatrice,Benedick>, <Benedick,Benedick>\}\\
  \end{assign}
\end{quoting}
Then what are the truth values of the following wffs?
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
  \item $\exists x\, Lmx$
  \item $\forall x\, Lxm$
  \item $(\exists x\, Lmx\supset Lmn)$
  \item $\forall x\, (Fx\equiv\lnot Gx)$
  \item $\forall x\, (Gx\supset(Lxm\vee\lnot Lmx))$
  \item $\forall x\, (Gx\supset\exists y\, Lxy)$
  \item $\exists x\, (Fx\land\forall y\, (Gy\supset Lxy))$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: assignments]

The only reason your one spilling-over environment spills over is that it contains no spaces so TeX can't break the line.

Comment: Can you explain `\par` and `\arraybackslash`? And, `.85\linewidth` looks like a hack. I'd rather have the length adapt to the surrounding.

Comment: The `\par` and skip are just to add some vertical spacing because things looked too close otherwise. (There's no vertical spacing as there would be putting `tabular` into a `table`, for example. The `\arraybackslash` ensures you can still end rows with `\\`. The `.85\linewidth` is a hack, yes.

Comment: @crocket Now it isn't a hack, though. At least, certainly, `.85\linewidth` is no longer a hack... ;).

Comment: Everything is good now.

Comment: LaTeX Is not great for logicians, I think. Not for formal symbolic logic of the kind philosophers do, anyway. (I don't know if mathematicians do this kind of thing but I assume not because LaTeX tends to have the tools for mathematicians. If it doesn't, a mathematician writes them.)

Comment: Do you know a better alternative to LaTeX for logic?

Comment: Afraid not. LaTeX is what the serious logicians I'm aware of use if they don't use Word. Believe me, Word is not a better alternative. They use LaTeX. Disjunction: they don't care about typographic details or they fix them *ad hoc* for their own stuff or there is some pot of logicians' gold somewhere with all the great tools they've written but sent there rather than CTAN. But no, I think this is the best option. It is just that it could be oh, so much better. We don't use semantic markup, for example. We *hard-code* appearance (symbol) rather than meaning (connective). That makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{quoting}{\parindent=0pt}
```